# Static block execution before main method

Tags: java, oop

Does static block of class execute before the main method of same class?

Example:

```
public class Example {

    static
    {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("bye");

    }
}
```

The output of this program is :

> hi
>
> bye

My doubt is why the output was not:

> bye

Comment: If the output was as you expected it, when did you expect the `static` block to execute? Why did you think so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer when i run the program using -- java example -- in  command prompt. In background java command executes main thread as -- example.main() -- which is similar to static method calling.
So statements in the static block executes first than my main method.

Answer (score 1):

Java will run the static intializers of a class before any method is called (or any instance is created).  The [JLS, Section 12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1), states:

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - A static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).
> - T is a top level class (§7.6) and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

Part of the initialization order is:

> 9. Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

Therefore, the static initializer is run first, and "hi" is printed; then `main` is called to print "bye".

Answer (score 0):

It only makes sense that things in the static block are executed before anything in main().  If you were to define "static PI = 3.14157;" wont you like it to be known in the main method?  Any other way will defeat the purpose.

As it turns out, static items are executed at the load time.